# Elastic Search Date Histogram is not working for 24 hour Format

Tags: elasticsearch

We are sending the IIS Logs from Log Stash to Elastic Search. But the date histogram search is not returning the correct result. Below is the Query

```
    {
      "size":0,
       "query":{  
          "filtered":{  
             "filter":{  
                "bool":{  
                   "must":[  
                      {  
                         "query":{  
                            "terms":{  
                               "request":[ 
                                  "/hotel/getrates.aspx",
                                  "/planner/travelplan.aspx"
                               ]
                            }
                         }
                      },
                      {  
                         "query":{  
                            "match":{  
                               "method":"GET"
                            }
                         }
                      },
                      {  
                         "range":{  
                            "EventTime":{  
                               "gte":"now-22h",
                               "lte":"now-16h"
                            }
                         }
                      }
                   ]
                }
             }
          }
       },
       "aggs":{  
          "timevalue":{  
             "date_histogram":{  
                "field":"EventTime",
                "interval":"hour",
                "format":"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
             },
             "aggs":{  
                "request":{  
                   "terms":{  
                      "field":"request"
                   },
                   "aggs":{  
                      "status":{  
                         "terms":{  
                            "field":"status"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Results are only for hour window 00-12, not for the 13-23.
Can someone please explain the reason.

Comment: Because you are limiting the results to 6 hours only `"EventTime":{  
                               "gte":"now-22h",
                               "lte":"now-16h"
                            }`?

Comment: When i posted this Query, these 6 hours contains the hour window, 11,12,13,14,15,16.

Comment: It looks like i found out the problem.. 'hh' means 1-12 and 'HH' means 0-23.

Comment: Good. Thanks for sharing.